# Proof that two linear maps are conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $K$ be some field and $V$ an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in GL(V)$ be two linear maps, and choose some basis $\{ u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n \}$ such that $\alpha$ has the representation matrix 
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & & & \ddots \\
  a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\beta$ has the matrix
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & & & \ddots \\
  b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b \in K$.

How to prove there exists some linear map $\gamma : V \to V$ such that 
$$
 \alpha = \gamma^{-1} \beta \gamma
$$
i.e. the maps are conjugate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try choosing $\gamma$ to be a diagonal matrix.  (Also, you have to assume $a$ and $b$ are nonzero (or else that they are both zero) for the result to be true.)

Comment: Yes. $$ \begin{pmatrix} b & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & & \ddots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & a \end{pmatrix} $$ works!